# Symbolic differentiation in functions and plugging only after the derivative has been done

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, differentials

I am doing some symbolic manipulation and misunderstand Mathematica. The code is as such:

```
x[t_] := t;
y1[t_, a_, b_] := b Sqrt[1 - t^2/a^2]
\[Phi]1[t_, a_, b_] := {x[t], y1[t, a, b]};
d\[Phi]1[t_, a_, b_] := D[\[Phi]1[t, a, b], t];
t1[s_, t0_, a_, b_] := s*d\[Phi]1[t0, a, b];
```

If I do:

```
t1[1, 0, 2, 1]
(* General::ivar: 0 is not a valid variable.*)
```

But

```
t1[s, t0, a, b]
```

gives the correct answer symbolically.

I think what is happening is that Mathematica plugs in `t0` into `D[\[Phi]1[t, a, b], t]` and only then it does the derivative. But then it is doing derivative with respect to `t0` which is technically wrong although it results in the same thing.

I want something like (but i dont think it can work this way), also, it is extra work, but I would think this should be default.

```
d\[Phi]1[t_, a_, b_] := D[\[Phi]1[s, a, b], s]/.s->t (* plug the value of t after you have done the derivative!*) ;
```

But I want it obviously the other way, how do I tell Mathematica to do it that way. By trial and error (I have no understanding why though) I have found that a candidate to correct it might be:

```
t1[s_, t0_, a_, b_] = s*d\[Phi]1[t0, a, b];
```

But reading the manual is just confusing things more because from that I understand it that it should work exactly opposite than what it is doing. Also with the `Set` symbol, the `t0,a,b` become blue in the gui which is driving me crazy as it seems I made a typo and that they are not defined.

What is the proper way to do such symbolic manipulations?

Comment: Use the long form of [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative.html), i.e.,  `d\[Phi]1[t_, a_, b_] := Derivative[1, 0, 0][\[Phi]1][t, a, b];`